# Solution of Bernoulli's differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following Bernoulli's equation:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=a(t)x-b(t)x^2$. with $x(0)=x_0$ and $a(t)>0$, $b(t)>0$.

On the way to solution, I make the substitution $u=1/x$ implying $u'=-x^{-2}\frac{dx}{dt}$ to transform it to the following equation in $u$.

$u'+a(t)u-b(t)=0$, which is a linear first order ODE, can be solved via Integrating factor: $e^{\int a(t)dt}$.

Leading to the following:

$\frac{d}{dt}\left[e^{\int a(t)dt)}*u\right]=b(t)e^{\int a(t)dt}$

$\implies u=\frac{1}{e^{\int a(t)dt}}\int b(t)e^{\int a(\tau)d\tau}dt$

Lets call $\int a(t)dt=\alpha(t)$. $\implies u=\frac{1}{e^\alpha}\int b(t)e^{\alpha}dt$.

Integrate by parts:

$\int b(t)e^{\alpha(t)}dt=b\int e^{\alpha(t)}dt-\int b(t)\left[\int e^{\alpha(\tau)}d\tau\right]dt+c$

which means:

$u=\frac{1}{e^{\alpha(t)}}\left[b\int e^{\alpha(t)}dt-\int b(t)\left[\int e^{\alpha(\tau)}d\tau\right]dt \right]$, this leads us to the solution $x(t)$ by substituting back $u=x^{-1}$ and $\alpha=\int a(t) dt$ i.e.,

$x(t)=\frac{e^{\int a(\tau)d\tau}}{\frac{1}{x_0}+b\int e^{\alpha(t)}dt-\int b(t)\left[\int e^{\alpha(\tau)}d\tau\right]dt}$.  where $c=1/x_0$.

However, the solution that I needed to come to is the following:

$x(t)=\frac{e^{\int a(\tau)d\tau}}{\frac{1}{x_0}+\int b(t)e^{\int a(\tau)d\tau}dt}$.

So I have one extra term in my solution $b(t)\int e^{\int a dt} $, that emerges from the 'uv' term in integration by parts. I would appreciate if someone can point out where I am doing a mistake?

Comment: Why do you apply integration-by-parts? If you use a formula with definite integrals and integration constants on the first form, you should get the reference solution.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Can you please state more clearly what you mean? what is that formula you are referring to? and why not integrate by parts when we have a situation $\int b(t)e^{\alpha(t)}dt$? What do you mean by 'first form'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already arrive at the solution formula
$$
u=e^{-\alpha}\int b(t)e^{\alpha}dt
$$
that you write in undetermined integrals. Add integration bounds
$$
u(t)=e^{-\alpha(t)}\left(u_0+\int_{t_0}^t b(s)e^{\alpha(s)}ds\right)
$$
and reverse the definition of $u$
$$
x(t)=\frac{e^{\alpha(t)}}{x_0^{-1}+\int_{t_0}^t b(s)e^{\alpha(s)}ds}
$$
and you get exactly the reference solution formula. No partial integration required.

Of course, if the original also has this mix of integration constant and undetermined integrals, then you are right in questioning this reference solution formula.

Comment: Oh Okay. Thanks for your explanation :)..